# Bind Devexpress girdview 2 from devexpress gridview1's callback

Tags: devexpress

I have two Devexpress gridview in a page.

I tried binding data to devexpress gridview2 from devexpress gridview1's custom callback method..

well no result is populated on devepress gridview 2.. it's bank...

The Code is as shown

```
ASPxGridView1_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
 DataTable dt_getdata = CommonBL.GetUserDefinedresult("select * from Accounts where ID='tr=009'");
if(dt_getdata!=null)
{
ASPxGridView2.DataSource = dt_getdata;
ASPxGridView2.DataBind();}}
```

No errors where found while debugging...why is this So??  Please Suggest a solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears because a callback response contains the information about a control which initiated this callback.  I.e. if the ASPxGridView2 is not a part of the ASPxGridView1, this code will not have any effect since the information about ASPxGridView is not passed to the client.  A possible solution is to send a callback to ASPxGridView2 and bind this control to data in its CustomCallback event handler.  Please also refer to the [How to show detail information in a separate ASPxGridView](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E70.aspx) example.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the next steps

1. Do the iteration of the rows and put into gridview2. Make sure that gridview2 is connected/linked with any database, otherwise no data will be retrieved.
2. Assign the DataSource of gridview1 to gridview2, keeping in mind to do the BindingSource.EndEdit() and Adapter.Update(Dataset.Table1).